# IE6, IE7, IE8 not displaying images inserted using jquery .html unless user right-clicks --> 'Show Picture' (Flash also on page)

Tags: jquery, flash, image, internet-explorer

I've got a strange issue which crops up in IE (6, 7 and 8) and when Flash is on a page: images display intermittently.

- Refreshing the page several times may or may not make the image display.
- Approximately 50% of the time the image displays
- If the image is not displayed there is space for the image and right-clicking 'Show Picture' *will* display the image.
- The problem does not appear in Safari, Firefox or Chrome.

Images are being inserted into the page using:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#MyDiv').html('<img src="tick_med.png" alt="tick">'+ // <-- displays intermittently
               'test'); // <-- this will always appear OK
});
```

I have tried:

- Using five different images (jpg and png)
- Using different IE versions
- Using a local (mac MAMP) and remote server
- Using ".load(fileName)" instead of ".html"
- Delaying the ".html" function by 5 seconds using show(500) and a callback function.

Help!

Rob

Comment: What is 'test' and why are you concatenating it to the image?  Try specifying the width and height for the image and also close the img element correctly :)

Comment: how is your DOCTYPE tag?

Comment: @RyanP13 The 'test' is to confirm that the ".html" action is working (and indeed the text 'test' always appears). The problem with the images not displaying occurs regardless of whether 'test' is included in the text above.

Comment: @madeinstefano DOCTYPE is: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of puzzling over this one I've stumbled across a workaround: add a delay before outputting any content triggered by Flash. So far tested on IE8 using a 50ms delay. By no means a perfect answer so I would be delighted if anyone can improve on this!

```
AFunctionCalledByFlash()
{
    $("#dummy2").toggle(50,function(){  // <--- this delay enables the image below to display properly in IE

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
             $('#Body').html('<div id="MyDiv"></div>')
             $('#MyDiv').html('<img src="tick_med.png" alt="tick">'); 
        });

    });
}
```

Based on my setup I suspect this issue is unlikely to affect many people: I have some content which is being loaded based on events triggered by Flash.

A few specific points in case anyone else has the problem:

- The error is observed only when Flash is used to trigger html content elsewhere on the page by calling a javascript function.
- There are no image issues when the content is added to the 'MyDiv' div separately to the Flash function call
- Delaying only the image does not fix the problem (as per my original question) - the parent divs must be delayed

Comment: The error is not necessarily caused by Flash.  The only thing flash is doing here is calling the function.  I'm having the same problem and all I am using is IE8, HTML & jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a DOCTYPE issue.  If you're using a STRICT (possibly Transitional as well) DOCTYPE you'll need to have the  tag be self closing.

`<img src="tick_med.png" alt="tick" />`

Note the closing slash.

Comment: Just tried adding the closing slash - not solved it unfortunately. Doctype is: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

If it's only happening in IE, you might look into putting the defer attribute into the script tag where your code runs from. The format is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js" defer></script>
```

or in a strict DOCTYPE and XHTML you would render it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

I'm not guaranteeing this will solve your problem, but it's something I would at least try. If it doesn't work there, you could also try it in the script that loads the Flash movie.